# Vendor id where to place in ecommerce app Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length =120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path,null=True, blank=True)
    featured        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    item_cart = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, blank=True)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=100,decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

where to place the vendor id in this model and how to implement for many shops with this datamodel
i did ecom website with this data model for a single shop

Comment: "where to place the vendor id in this model" which model are you referring to? Can you please also show us the vendor class or point out which one is it?

Comment: I would suggest creating a Vendor class and a new field in Product class, the new field would be a Foreign Key. You can have many products linked to a single vendor.